# Why would one user not have permission to run explorer.exe until after a different user had?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-explorer, user-profiles

User profiles on a win7 box I have the displeasure of administrating all got corrupted (windows would create a default fallback profile on each login).

I created a new profile (an administer) and transfered exiting profile files into it following this:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/fix-a-corrupted-user-profile

Something strange is happening. The new profile is unable to open explorer.exe

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.
```

I tried a variety of things including confirming the permissions on C:\Windows\Registration:

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/5218-63-cant-explorer#t170268

What I've noticed is that if I log in as a different new administrator user and open explorer.exe and then log in as the administrator with the problem explorer will work just fine.

What is it about the permissions on explorer.exe that cause this behavior?

What I want to achieve is to have the problem account open explorer.exe without having to log in as the other user first.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
Here are permissions and Owner Screens of the offending profile:
```

[image: permissions profile dir]
[image: Owner profile dir]

```
Here are permissions and Owner Screens of Windows dir:
```

[image: permissions win dir]
[image: Owner win dir]

```
Here are permissions of explorer.exe:
```

[image: explorer.exe perm]

Comment: Checked for viruses, or Safe Mode, Sir? or have you accidently excluded all .exe files for that user in Group Policy, or is anything amiss at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

Comment: Could you show us a screen shot of the permissions?  I would take ownership and then re-assign permissions.

Comment: @GuyThomas Not sure what you want to see permissions of.  I've attached screens of the offending profile and the Windows dir

Comment: @JamesYoung Safe mode looks good. Nothing looks obviously wrong with the Reg Keys

Comment: Thanks for the screen shots, sadly when compared with my user permissions, I cannot see any problems or faults.  Maybe that in itself is a clue.

Answer (score 3):

Try resetting all Windows file permissions to default.

In an [elevated command prompt](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-elevated-command-prompt/) type the following command.

`secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose`

If that fails you can always try a system restore.

Comment: I get "The task has completed. warnings occurred for some attributes during this operation. It's okay to ignore the warning.
See log %windir%\security\logs\scesrv.log for detail info." Problem still persists though.

Comment: I recommend you read this post. http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/solved-locked-out-of-group-policy-428518.html#post2426814

Answer (score 1):

Make sure if the new account is correctly added to the administrator group;
If it is indeed correctly added in administrator group, run a Malware scan, then run the following line on a elevated command prompt:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Your windows cd will be asked to be inserted if changes to your system are needed.

Comment: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Comment: change the ownership of your `%root%\windows` folder and subfolders to your newly created account. that would solve the issue. (replace TrustedInstaller with your account name)

Comment: Does that have any unintended side effects ?

Comment: none at all, since your newly created account is placed inside the admin group.

Comment: Interestingly it does not seem to have solved this issue ...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, however, I just solved the same problem on my Windows 7 Pro laptop and thought I would contribute what I believe caused the problem and my solution.

I believe my c:\users\{user_name} directory became corrupted after I did something dumb.  After this my computer had the exact same symptoms described in this post.

I was able to logon and create a 2nd administrator account and from the new admin user account I was able to restore the directory.  Once the data was restored, I was able to logon to the original account and explorer and other programs worked without the dreaded access denied message.

From other reading I did online, it appears that the ntuser.dat file might have been the culprit; if I understand correctly, this file is copied to the window's registry at logon time and defines the profile for the logged on user.  If true, this means that I corrupted the stored version of the user portion of the registry for this account and restoring the file reversed the corruption.

I hope this helps someone else.